# How to set position to checkbox in listview multichoice

Tags: android, listview, checkbox, position

I need to position the checkbox to the left on a listview (multichoice). 
This should be simple, but I can not get done.

```
<LinearLayout
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_weight="1"
   android:orientation="vertical" >

   <TextView
       android:id="@+id/lblTipoSolucionTarea"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_marginLeft="22dp"
       android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
       android:gravity="right|center_vertical"
       android:text="Tareas:"
       android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
       android:textColor="#7c3808"
       android:textSize="22sp" />

       <ListView
           android:id="@+id/lstTipoSolucionTarea"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="145dp"
           android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
           android:background="@android:drawable/list_selector_background"
           android:choiceMode="multipleChoice"
           android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay" >
        </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

ArrayAdapter ListViewAdapterTarea = new ArrayAdapter(oPadre, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, lTipoSolucion.get(0).getTiposSolucionTareas())

```
{
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        View v = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
        ((TextView) v).setTypeface(oPadre.goFontBold);
        ((TextView) v).setTextSize(lblTipoSolucionTarea.getTextSize());                             
        return v;
    }
};
lstTipoSolucionTarea.setAdapter(ListViewAdapterTarea);
```

Thank you

Regards

Comment: post your relevant code

Comment: Don't know what is the real problem here, but you can always define your own layout for each item in the `listview` and specify what each item should contain and where.. `android:choiceMode` does not add checkboxes for you:P

Comment: Hi, Karolina. Please check my personal picture, this is the problem. I'm new in stackoverflow and I can't post images. I need set to checkboxs to the left.

Comment: Please post the row layout xml.

Comment: You can always use something standard like [android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice.xml](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/layout/simple_list_item_multiple_choice.xml)

Answer (score 1):

Your `ArrayAddapter` uses `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice` which has checkboxes on the left side. To fix your issue you can define your own layout. The snippet below should solve your problem. Save it as `row_item.xml` and use with your listview adapter.

```
<LinearLayout
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:orientation="horizontal">

   <CheckBox
     android:id="@+id/chbox"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"/>

   <TextView
     android:id="@+id/title"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Note that you will have to populate all the fields inside the `getView()` method.

Hope that helps somehow :)